# setting min , max and exact no. of arguments required for option using commons cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I am using Apache Commons cli. I have created different Options using OptionBuilder:

```
final Option name = OptionBuilder.withArgName().hasArgs().withDescription()
                     .withLongOpt()
```

My problem is that I want to have a fixed number of arguments for an Option. If a user passes fewer or more arguments, it should throw exception.

For other options I want to set minimum and maximum numbers of arguments allowed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the exact number of required arguments with [`Option.setArgs(int num)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html#setArgs%28int%29).

It is not possible to set a minimum and maximum. Perhaps you could use `setArgs` to set a maximum and check the minimum number manually. Alternatively, raise a feature request on the Jira site: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CLI